# how to retrieve array element with xpath

Tags: java, xpath, xml-rpc

I want to get value of serviceOfferingActiveFlag of particular id serviceOfferingID. Sample XML is below.

The point which is bothering me is that serviceOfferingID memeber comes after serviceOfferingActiveFlag.

How i get value of particular serviceOfferingID?

```
<methodResponse>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>responseCode</name>
<value><i4>0</i4></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferings</name>
<value>
<array>
<data>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name>
<value><boolean>0</boolean></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingID</name>
<value><i4>1</i4></value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name>
<value><boolean>0</boolean></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingID</name>
<value><i4>2</i4></value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name>
<value><boolean>0</boolean></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingID</name>
<value><i4>3</i4></value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingActiveFlag</name>
<value><boolean>0</boolean></value>
</member>
<member>
<name>serviceOfferingID</name>
<value><i4>4</i4></value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</data>
</array>
</value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodResponse>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
$methodResponse/params/param/value/struct/member[name eq 'serviceOfferings']/value
/array/data/value/struct[member[name eq 'serviceOfferingID']/value/i4 eq '1']
/member[name eq 'serviceOfferingActiveFlag']/value
```

The above would get you corresponding value element for 'serviceOfferingActiveFlag' where 'serviceOfferingID' equals 1

I have used complete xpath to navigate. You can use '//' wherever needed to cut down on the xpath length. But note that using '//' is brings down the performance of the query. You could tailor some filters in the xpath according to your requirement.

Comment: Following expression working good     "//struct[member[name = 'serviceOfferingID' and value/* = '2']]/member[name = 'serviceOfferingActiveFlag']/value/*"